# How to disable Bootstrap nav-stacked for small devices?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap navbar defined as follows: `<ul class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked'>` which results in a vertical navigation (sidebar).

Now I want to disable the `nav-stacked` class on small and extra small devices, so that the menu appears horizontally instead of vertically.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only styles being applied by the `.nav-stacked` class are as follows...

```
nav-stacked > li {
  float: none;
}
.nav-stacked > li + li {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Use a media-query to override them (back to `.nav-pills`) at the desired break-point. Which would look something like this... [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/t6qctj04/)

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .nav-stacked > li {
      float: left;
    }
    .nav-stacked > li + li {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-left: 2px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two Way :
1- use java script and change the class for sm and xs devices

2- Create a sidebar and a horizontal navigation. add proper classes to each of them

Comment: Solution 1: I don't want to rely on JavaScript for that.
Solution 2: Good candidate, but a hack.

Comment: you can also use less for this! but it's kind a java script and not neccessery!